# NSLayoutAttribute's explained

Tags: ios, autolayout

I find the documentation a little sparse. Here's an example

```
NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
  The trailing edge of the object’s alignment rectangle.
  Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
  Declared in NSLayoutConstraint.h
```

Specifically I want all these explained

```
NSLayoutAttributeLeft
NSLayoutAttributeRight
NSLayoutAttributeTop
NSLayoutAttributeBottom
NSLayoutAttributeLeading
NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
NSLayoutAttributeWidth
NSLayoutAttributeHeight
NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
NSLayoutAttributeBaseline
NSLayoutAttributeLastBaseline
NSLayoutAttributeFirstBaseline
NSLayoutAttributeLeftMargin
NSLayoutAttributeRightMargin 
NSLayoutAttributeTopMargin
NSLayoutAttributeBottomMargin 
NSLayoutAttributeLeadingMargin 
NSLayoutAttributeTrailingMargin 
NSLayoutAttributeCenterXWithinMargins
NSLayoutAttributeCenterYWithinMargins
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image: constraint-nouns]

Painted that for a talk. It could be better. Here is the [PSD](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5250652/constraint-nouns.psd).

Comment: LOL! I love that you had this one already prepared. BUT! This example is a Chinese character. Trailing and Leading should be the other way round. Also, you have mis-labelled top and bottom. Left and Right are also missing.

Comment: I renamed top and bottom. Didn't the Chinese government mandated left to right, top to bottom writing decades ago? (I'm honestly not sure)

Comment: Ah, you may be right about the direction then. I just always assumed it was a rtl language.

Comment: Drawing is really good and clear! iOS 8 got quite a few extra attributes which is missing from this drawing. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Maybe somewhat misleading. The drawing indicates that top, bottom, leading, and trailing are gaps but they represent edges.